# Issue controlling Enter Key behavior in a TabPanel

Tags: asp.net, tabs

I have a web application using Tabcontainer controls. 
I have defined a HeaderTemplate in a TabPanel and dropped an ImageButton control on it so that I can have a "close panel" X image on the tab.
I am manually controlling the tab visibility from code.
From this image OnClick event - I execute code that does some clean up and manually closes the tab.

Here is the display code:

```
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabREVRES" runat="server" HeaderText="" Visible="false" DefaultButton="T2ResSearch">
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="ResHdrLbl1" runat="server" Text="Open Resource Review" Font-Size="Smaller"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ResHdrClose" ImageUrl="../Images/XinBox.jpg" ToolTip="Close Review Tab" OnClick="ResTabClose_Click"
                Height="15" ImageAlign="TextTop" Width="15" />   
</HeaderTemplate>
```

I have a Textbox and Search button on the page within this TabPanel.  I want the Enter key to default to the Search button.  However the Enter key is defaulting  to the TabPanel ImageButton control Onclick event - thereby executing the codebehind logic to close the tab.
As you can see from the code sample - I tried adding a DefaultButton= to the TabPanel but that is not working.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the cleanest approach - but I solved this with the following code in case it helps anyone:

In tabs where I have no button controls - I am stopping the Enter key from closing the tab with this javascript:

```
function stopRKey(evt) {
        var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
        var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
        if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type == "text")) { return false; }
    }
    document.onkeypress = stopRKey;
```

For Tabs with button controls - I make one of them the default as follows:

```
this.Form.DefaultButton = this.mydefaultbuttonID.UniqueID;
```